# Find a specific value, copy an offset

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do the following. The value that appears in cell B63 of the dropdowns sheet may sometimes appear in column C in the Review sheet. On the review sheet, I want it to find the section that start with the words "Before After" in column A (RngStart), find the B63 value in column C and, when it does, copy the value in column F (Offset (1,3)). All information is pasted to a sheet called Mkting starting at cell A7 (RngDest). Right now this is my working code but it does not work. Help!

```
Sub test()

Dim RngStart As Range, RngDest As Range
Dim Sector1 As String

Sector1 = Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("B63").Value

With Sheets("Mkting")
    Set RngDest = .Range("A7")
End With

Set ws = Sheets("Review")
Set RngStart = ws.Columns("A").Find("Before After", , xlValues, xlPart)

With Sheets("Review").Range("C" & RngStart.row & ":" & "C1000")
    .AutoFilter 1, Sector1
    .Offset(1, 3).Copy RngDest
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.  The only part I got confused about was Offset(1,3) in your paragraph.  This code grabs the value from the Column F line that matched.  If you want the next line down from the match, change *RngDest.Value = Sheets("Review").Range("F" & ctr).Value* to *RngDest.Value = Sheets("Review").Range("F" & ctr **+ 1**).Value*.

I recommend using the [Like Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796(v=office.15).aspx) for your goal.  Place *Option Compare Text* at the top of your module either right below *Option Explicit* or as the 1st line if you don't use *Option Explicit* (which you always should.)

The rest is a simple loop through the Review worksheet looking for those 2 criteria you specified.  It places each match it finds on the Mkting worksheet, starting at cell A7.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub test()
    Dim RngDest As Range
    Dim Sector1 As String
    Dim MaxRow As Long
    Dim ctr As Long

Sector1 = Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("B63").Value
Set RngDest = Sheets("Mkting").Range("A7")
MaxRow = Sheets("Review").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For ctr = 1 To MaxRow
    If Sheets("Review").Range("A" & ctr).Value Like "Before After*" And Sheets("Review").Range("C" & ctr).Value Like Sector1 Then
        RngDest.Value = Sheets("Review").Range("F" & ctr).Value
        Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next ctr

End Sub
```

Comment: Nicely done, appreciate the use of wildcards here :)